# Loops to remove rows and add rows in the same spreadsheet won't run correctly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have been working on a script that adds and deletes rows from a number of spreadsheets according to values in an ID column.

In a master sheet,

- If the first column has **New Student**...add the ID of the student above to an array.( so we can loop for these IDs in the sheets and add a row under them)
- If the first column has **Remove Student**...add the ID of the student in
  this row to an array.(so we can delete these rows from the sheets)

Ex. of Master Student List:
[image: Ex. of Master Student List:]

Ex. of data sheet:

[image]

My script loops through all the spreadsheets in a folder properly.  My issue is with my loops that add and remove rows.  If they both run on the same sheet, they mess everything up.  I have both loops looping backward through the values in the ID column and through the arrays to try and stop it from grabbing the wrong rows being that it's adding and deleting them as it goes. But' they are not working.

---

Both of the loops work perfectly if they are run independently.  Its when one loop has to remove students and the other has to add rows for students that it removes the wrong student row and adds the row in the wrong place etc.  I know it has to do with my syntax in the loops, but I am not very good with them.  Any advice you guys can give would be greatly appreciated.  even if it means taking a different approach to the whole process.  I only added the code below that loops through each spreadsheet, being that the rest is working properly.  I hope this makes sense.  I can add the rest of the code if it helps, I just know we are suppose to stay specific on here. Thanks so much! Brandon

```js
       ssName = thisSS.getName(),
       ssUrl = thisSS.getUrl(),
       archiveSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Archive Spreadsheetheet ID'), //Data Report Sheet ID
       archiveSheet = archiveSS.getSheets()[0],
       archiveSheetNewRow = archiveSheet.getLastRow(),
       archiveNewRow = archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1,
       dataReportRange = archiveSheet.getRange(archiveNewRow,1,1,1);
       
    Logger.log("New student array after break - " + AboveNewStudentArr);
    Logger.log("Archive student array after break - " + archiveStudentArr);
  
   /*---------------Loops---------------*/
   
/* If file is in filesToExclude skip it, if not proceed */  
if (filesToExclude.indexOf(ssName)!==-1) {
   } else {  
   
   /* Array of values for loops below */  
   var k, t, addRowArray = AboveNewStudentArr;  //AboveNewStudentArr - is ths array of Ids to place a new row below 
   var addRowArrayLen = addRowArray.length;
    
   /* Loop through the addRowArray aray */ 
   for (var k = addRowArrayLen-1; k>=0 ;k--) {
      /* Loop through the idRange */
      for(var l = idRange.length-1; l>0 ; l--){ 
          /* If value in idRange matches value in addRowArray, add a row below it */ 
          if (idRange[l] == addRowArray[k]) {    
               var rowFormulas = classData.getRange(l+1,1,1,classData.getLastColumn()).getFormulas();
               thisSS.insertRowAfter(l+1).getRange(l+2,1,1,classData.getLastColumn()).setFormulas(rowFormulas);
               Logger.log("Added row for student with ID# " + t);
    }  
  }
}
    
    /* Array of values for loops below */
    var i, s, removeStudent = archiveStudentArr;  //archiveStudentArr - is ths array of Ids of rows to remove
    var arrayLength = removeStudent.length; 
    
    /* Loop through the removeStudent aray */ 
    for (var i = arrayLength-1; i>=0 ;i--) {
        s = removeStudent[i];
       /* Loop through the idRange */
       for(var j = idRange.length-1; j>0 ; j--){   
           /* If value in idRange matches value in removeStudent, remove the row */  
           if (idRange[j] == removeStudent[i]) {    
                var row = Number(j)+1;
                var lastColumn = classData.getLastColumn()
                classData.deleteRow(row);
                Logger.log("Removed student with ID# " + s + " by deleting row " + row);
          }
        }       
      }
```

Comment: How do you get `idRange` array?

Answer (score 0):

For complex work flows, it's good to have separate functions that do generic tasks, and keep the main function as short as possible with just the decision making logic.  That way, it's easier to think through how the program is flowing.

So, the first thing I recommend, is to create separate functions for populating the arrays, and doing any tasks.  Only have decision making code in the main function.

### Main Function:

```
function mainLogicForStudentIDs() {
  //Process either the addition or deletion of rows first, independently.
  //Find any rows that need to be removed
  var rtrnInfoFromTheFindRemoveFnc = fncToFindRowsToRemove();

  if (rtrnInfoFromTheFindRemoveFnc !== false) {
    fncToRemoveRows(rtrnInfoFromTheFindRemoveFnc);
  };

  //Find any rows with new students
  var rtrnInfoFromTheFindNewStudentsFnc = fncNewStudents();

  if (rtrnInfoFromTheFindNewStudentsFnc !== false) {
    fncProcessNewStudents(rtrnInfoFromTheFindNewStudentsFnc);
  };
};
```

### Separate Function to Find rows to Remove.

```
function fncToFindRowsToRemove() {
  var arrayOfRowsToDelete = [];

  for () {}; //Build the array of rows to delete

  if (arrayOfRowsToDelete.length === 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return arrayOfRowsToDelete;
  };
};
```

### Remove the Rows

```
function fncToRemoveRows(arrayPassedIn) {
  //Loop through all rows to delete, and delete them.

};
```

Comment: I was hoping you would take a look....I am going to include the rest of the code so you can see how the arrays are generated and passed.  I would like to do things the way you posted, but I am not sure how to include it.  And I still am not sure how to make the loops do what I want them to do.

Answer (score 0):

If your code works independently correct, issue might be on indexes of arrays since array length is keep changing. so after you add new row and before you remove a row, you need to initiate **`idRange`** array.

```
/* Loop through the addRowArray array */ 
***********
idRange = //re initiate this array

********
/* Loop through the removeStudent array */
```